# Trying to setup CI with gitlab and a remote server

Tags: php, github, gitlab, remote-server, gitlab-ci

Push to gitlab repo is working fine.Now a web hook is added to the gitlab on push to call a file in remote server.The PHP code present in that file is to `git pull`.

when I do git pull from terminal it works fine.But when I hit that URL a error displaying

"**sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified**"

This error also appears when the hook hits the link once the master branch is pushed to gitlab repo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message tries to prompt you for a password but can't, since no terminal is present.

To prevent this from happening you need to edit your `sudoers` file. On your machine type `sudo visudo` and add the following line:

```
username ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/git
```

This will allow `username` to use git without any password.

The username could be `www-data` or `apache` in a default apache installation but that is something you need to check yourself.